# Strikethrough GridViewColumn Member Under Certain Condition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

I have a `GridViewColumn` that lists file paths. I have a filewatcher, and if the file is moved out of the watched directory, I want to strike through the filepath in my `GridViewColumn`.

Here is my XAML for the `GridViewColumn`:

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="FileNameHeader" Header="File Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding filename}" />
```

I can add a property to the structure that contains `filename` such as `FileExists()` which would return `false` if the file is missing. Then, I just need a way to set the strikethrough text. Could I possibly use some sort of styling?

Comment: Why is my question being voted to close? What's wrong?

Comment: You can accomplish it with DataTemplate in GridViewColumn.CellTemplate.  BTW, as you know, a question is expected to include some details on what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property of type `bool` e.g. `Exists` to your file structure to indicate that a file exists or not. Do not forget to [implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)  so that changes to the property are reflected in the user interface. In the following, I assume that your file structure is a class called `FileData`. Make sure to change it to the real name in your project. I changed the property name `filename` to `Filename`. It is a good practice to adhere to common naming guidelines, see [Capitalization Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) for reference.

In order to apply strikethough to the text, you need to create a custom `CellTemplate`, as there is no direct way to style the column. In the [`DataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) you create a `TextBlock` to display the `Filename`. Add a style to the `TextBlock` with a [`DataTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) that sets the [`Strikethrough`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.textdecorations.strikethrough?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-textdecorations-strikethrough) text decoration depending on the `Exists` property of your file structure.

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="FileNameHeader" Header="File Name">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileData}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Filename}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Exists}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Strikethrough"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

You do not necessarily need to set the `DataType`, but it helps with autocomplete in the editor.

Comment: Your suggestion worked, but instead of INotifyPropertyChanged, I refreshed the ListView after the file was removed (in the filewatcher event). Is this not a good idea compared to your suggestion? Is your suggestion better for performance, since maybe yours doesn't refresh the entire thing and just that row?

Comment: @MemeMachine Adding or removing only affected items is more elegant and prevents allocating a whole new collection and potentially other objects and only updates the necessary parts in the user interface. Therefore, you should prefer this approach in general as it is usually better performing. However, in case that there is a large number of files and you remove hundreds or more of them at once, there may not be any performance benefit. The performance could even degrade due to the overhead of change notifications and user interface updates for each item.

Comment: @MemeMachine I would suggest to go with the elegant approach as long as there is no performance issue and if there is, start profiling the application to find the reasons for it. If it is the collection update try replacing the entire list and check again if it benefits performance for your use cases.